# CiviMail recipient listing behavior on Wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, civimail, multisite

I am running CiviCRM 4.7.27 on WP 4.9.1. This is a multisite and I am seeing some odd behavior when composing an email with CiviMail regarding the "Groups" available recipients listing. For non-admin users of one any one of the sites, they are not getting the group they are permissioned to see when composing a CiviMail. I am not seeing any patterns on why they are seeing only the same 3 groups (we have over 50). Those 3 groups are tied to different organizations.

Is there a certain way this is supposed to be permissioned? How does civimail determine the group recipients for a multisite domain?

Comment: Do all the non admin see the same groups, no matter their organisations? It might be a cache issue, are you using memcache or regular civi? try clearing your cache and create a new mailing with a non admin user, see what happens

Comment: I cleared the civi cache. They see the same groups.